# Are there other unseen Archangels in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

I remember in one episode in Supernatural, where someone mentions how the Archangels destroyed the Knights of Hell. It got me thinking, because at that point, the only Archangels that we know about that were operating in heaven were Michael and Raphael, since Gabriel was under 'witness protection' and Lucifer was all locked up. Another example, is when Metatron talked about God's departure, and how the 'Archangels' cried for his his return. Again at that point, there were only two in heaven we know of.

I also vaguely recall several other instances of 'Archangels', although I can't cite them exactly. The thing is, would one really use the plural form when referring only to Michael and Raphael? Another thing, is when Metatron called himself an Archangel in one of the tablets,  Sam and Dean didn't find that weird (almost like they themselves weren't 100% sure on all of the Archangels).

So my question is, is that were there only 4 Archangels originally, or could there possibly be more we haven't seen?

Answer (score 2):

No.

This is implied in several parts of the show, most recently in S11E10 by Lucifer.

> When he says, of the archangels, that Gabriel and Raphael are dead, Michael is crazy, and therefore he's the only one who can fight the Darkness.

Aside from this, any remaining archangels would have taken leadership of heaven.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [wiki](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Archangels) there are only 4 Archangels in supernatural at the moment. However, that does not mean they can't introduce more if they so desire.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is true that there are only 4 original archangels and they were brothers. 
However, I believe that throughout the series, regular angels take an archangel's responsibilities into their own hands.

It was an archangel's job to protect humanity, but throughout the episodes other angels such as Castiel, Hannah, maybe even Metatron do that, it seems obvious to me that there are only 4 official archangels, and many self-declared and self-proven archangels.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as it specifically asks about _original_, or _true_ archangels - those who were created as archangels by god.

Comment: well i did say that there were only 4 original archangels